# Cannot build Android Studio Emulator because it cannot find the fonts

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile

I have been attempting to add custom fonts into my Android Studio Project. In my res/fonts folder, I have defined my "roboto_condensed.xml" font family with all the .ttf files included int the directory. The result renders fine in the preview, but when I try to build in the Android Studio emulator, I get this error:

```
Android resource linking failed
com.example.connectfour.app-mergeDebugResources-26:/values/values.xml:5496: error: resource font/roboto_condensed" (aka com.example.connectfour:font/roboto_condensed") not found.
com.example.connectfour.app-mergeDebugResources-26:/values/values.xml:5496: error: resource font/roboto_condensed" (aka com.example.connectfour:font/roboto_condensed") not found.
com.example.connectfour.app-mergeDebugResources-26:/values/values.xml:9090: error: resource font/roboto_condensed" (aka com.example.connectfour:font/roboto_condensed") not found.
com.example.connectfour.app-mergeDebugResources-26:/values/values.xml:9090: error: resource font/roboto_condensed" (aka com.example.connectfour:font/roboto_condensed") not found.
com.example.connectfour.app-mergeDebugResources-26:/values/values.xml:9095: error: resource font/roboto_condensed" (aka com.example.connectfour:font/roboto_condensed") not found.
com.example.connectfour.app-mergeDebugResources-26:/values/values.xml:9095: error: resource font/roboto_condensed" (aka com.example.connectfour:font/roboto_condensed") not found.
error: failed linking references.
```

Here's my xml font family file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <!-- Roboto Condensed Bold -->
    <font
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="700"
        app:font="@font/roboto_condensed_bold" />

<!--     Roboto Condensed Bold Italic-->
    <font
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:fontWeight="700"
        app:font="@font/roboto_condensed_bold_italic" />

    <!-- Roboto Condensed Italic -->
    <font
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/roboto_condensed_italic" />

    <!-- Roboto Condensed Light -->
    <font
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="300"
        app:font="@font/roboto_condensed_light" />

    <!-- Roboto Condensed Light Italic -->
    <font
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:fontWeight="300"
        app:font="@font/roboto_condensed_light_italic" />

    <!-- Roboto Condensed Regular -->
    <font
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/roboto_condensed_regular" />
</font-family>
```

and here is how I have defined my style that uses the font in styles.xml:

```
    <style name="h1">
        <item name="android:textSize">50sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textFontWeight">700</item>
        <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto_condensed"</item>
    </style>
```

Attached is how the app renders in preview
[image: Attached is how the app renders in preview]

I tried going into my build.gradle for the app module and adding `implementation ("com.google.android.gms:fonts:18.0.1")` in the dependencies section. But the it couldn't find the module so that was no help